# Find last evicted url/key from Squid

Tags: squid

I am trying to find the last url/key evicted from the squid for some analysis purpose. Till now I have tried different log patterns available in squid. Squid documentation suggests cache_store_log  Shows which objects are ejected from the cache, and which objects are saved and for how long. I am not able to find the last key evicted with the help of this log. Please suggest other alternatives to find the last key/url evicted. 
2)Ways to find all the urls stored in squid at sometime.